# Javascript - CSS style for an element does not show when appended

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a problem in javascript regarding appending of values to an element's innerHTML (specifically div element). The problem is, everytime I append a value to an element's innerHTML, the CSS style for the appended value does not show. For example, when I run this script:

```
    <script>
        var content=<?php

        echo json_encode("
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>HELLO</td>
            </tr>
        ");

        ?>;

        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=content;
    </script>

    //followed by this script which appends values
    //the script below does not show CSS style

    <script>
        var content=<?php

        echo json_encode("
            <tr>
                <td>HI</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        ");

        ?>;

        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML+=content;
    </script>
```

I added this picture to further elaborate what I'm talking about.
[image: img]

The CSS style used in the image above:

```
    table
    {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        width:100%;
    }

    th
    {
        background-color:#8a855f;
        padding:3px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-align:center;
        border:1px solid #686440;
        color:#edebdc;
    }

    td
    {
        background-color:#d1cebd;
        padding:3px;
        text-align:center;
        border:1px solid #686440;
        color:#686440;
    }
```

Comment: can you just show in what way you are applying the css

Comment: added the CSS style used in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because it is automatically taking the closing `</table>` tag. See the console and check the Elements, you will get the problem.

I would suggest you to first append all the values in the `var content` and then set that value as innerHTML of the div.

```
<script>
    var content=<?php

    echo json_encode("
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>HELLO</td>
        </tr>
    ");

    ?>;


</script>

//followed by this script which appends values
//the script below does not show CSS style

<script>
    content +=<?php

    echo json_encode("
        <tr>
            <td>HI</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    ");

    ?>;

    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=content;
</script>
```

Comment: No use of thank you dude... I got what I wanted(score) and you got what you wanted(Answer)...